# Por que es que el decorador property crea un atributo de clase? (Python)

Tags: python

-Como bien doy a entender con el titulo, ya conozco bien como es que trabaja el decorador `property`, simplemente crea un atributo de clase y lo actualiza constantemente con los metodos que definimos. Sin embargo, no termino de entender por que razon es que genera un atributo de clase y no de instancia, esto lo considero sumamente peor ... Obviamente hay una razon de ser de aquello, con lo cual la pregunta seria: "cual es la razon de que property cree atributos de clase y no de instancia"

Argumento ...

```
class persona:
    def __init__(self, nombre, apellido):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellido = apellido
    @property
    def nombre_completo(self):
        return self.nombre.capitalize() + ' ' + self.apellido.capitalize()
    @nombre_completo.setter
    def nombre_completo(self, nuevo_nombre):
        nombre,apellido = nuevo_nombre.split(' ')
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellido = apellido
    @nombre_completo.deleter
    def nombre_completo(self):
        del persona.nombre_completo

persona_nueva = persona('Juan', 'Peres')
print(persona_nueva.nombre_completo)
persona.nombre_completo = 'Nelson Martinez'
print(persona_nueva.nombre_completo)
print(persona.nombre_completo)
print(persona.__dict__['nombre_completo'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para responder a esto debemos tomar como referencia el *motor* detrás de `property`: El Descriptor Protocol.

Básicamente, esto se trata de que todo objeto que sea un atributo de otro objeto y que contemple los métodos `__get__` y (opcionalmente) `__set__` y (opcionalmente) `__del__`, es tratado de una forma especial por el intérprete al momento de que dicho objeto sea invocado para su lectura, escritura o borrado, respectivamente.

Sin embargo, para que esto suceda, el objeto debe ser declarado como una variable de clase de la clase a través de la cual el objeto vaya a ser referenciado.

Como ya mencioné, el type `property` implementa el Descriptor Protocol. Es así como *mágicamente* podemos definir comportamientos a ejecutar para el establecimiento, acceso y eliminación de los atributos decoradorados con este type.

Así que sí, básicamente la respuesta a tu pregunta viene dada por las reglas inherentes de este protocolo. De hecho, en su propia [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) se dice esto taxativamente:

> To use the descriptor, it must be stored as a class variable in another class

Realmente no entiendo por qué lo consideras peor que sea así en comparación a que sea un atributo de instancia, o qué beneficio le ves si así lo fuese. Sería interesante saber qué ventajas consideras que pudiesen haber. No obstante, estoy seguro que al leer la (excelente) guía de Raymond Hettinger a la que hice referencia arriba, podrás entender a profundidad que los casos de uso para los cuales los descriptores son usados están cubiertos perfectamente de la manera en que ya han sido concebidos.